# jQuery how to check boxes from binary field

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 5 checkboxes.

- Checkbox All
- Checkbox 1
- Checkbox 2
- Checkbox 3
- Checkbox 4

From server I populate a table and I create in the  element an attribute: 'data-options="0101"'.

I need to check my checkboxes depending on this binary values, so each position mean the Checkbox index and the value could be 0 or 1 ( checked or unchecked).

- 0101 means Checkbox 2 and 4 are checked.
- 1111 means all `checkboxe`'s checked this 'Checkbox All' must be checked also.

> Any clue?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us what you have attempted, as well as other details about the fields.  It is also curious as to why you are not making the server make the checkboxes checked to begin with, rather than using javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `data-options` and loop through every character from it then `check/uncheck` the `checkboxe`'s, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

---

**Check all case ("1111"):**

```js
var options = $('span').data('options');
var check_all = true;

$.each(options.toString().split(''), function(i,v){
  if(v=="1")
    $('.my-checkbox:eq('+i+')').prop('checked',true);
  else
    check_all = false;
});

if( check_all )
  $(".check-all").prop('checked',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-options="1111"></span>

<input class="check-all" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_all"/>Checkbox All
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_1"/>Checkbox 1
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_2"/>Checkbox 2
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_3"/>Checkbox 3
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_4"/>Checkbox 4
```

**Other values case ("1001"):**

```js
var options = $('span').data('options');
var check_all = true;

$.each(options.toString().split(''), function(i,v){
  if(v=="1")
    $('.my-checkbox:eq('+i+')').prop('checked',true);
  else
    check_all = false;
});

if( check_all )
  $(".check-all").prop('checked',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-options="1001"></span>

<input class="check-all" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_all"/>Checkbox All
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_1"/>Checkbox 1
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_2"/>Checkbox 2
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_3"/>Checkbox 3
<br>
<input class="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="checkbox_4"/>Checkbox 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposed solution. You can directly access each character inside the string as if the string is an array. Loop through each character and check if it is '0' (false) or '1' (true) and check the corresponding checkboxes. If the number of checked checkboxes is 4, then you check the Check All.

```js
var arr = $('div').attr('data-options');
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
 isChecked = arr[i] == 0 ? false : true;
 $("input[id='" + i + "']").prop('checked', isChecked);
} 
if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 4) {
  $('input[id=all]').prop('checked', true);
} else {
  $('input[id=all]').prop('checked', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-options='1110'>
1110
</div>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='all'/>All</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='0'/>1</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='1'/>2</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='2'/>3</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='3'/>4</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok since you have no code sample nor sample classes/ names i am making basic assumptions.
Lets say each of the checkbox have a common class say "checker"

```
var str = '';
$(".checker").each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
     str = str + '1';
   else 
     str = str + '0'; 
});

$("#yourElementSelector").data("options",str);
```

Also since this seems a bit like your homework :P you could just try adding an if/else to check for the "Check All" Checkbox !

Comment: It looks like you are constructing the binary string.  He seems to be saying he already has that, and he wants to set the checkbox state from it.  You went backwards, :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I need the other way, from data-options to checkboxes.